# What causes this vue-router async component error - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.__esModule')?

Tags: ios, vuejs2, mobile-safari, vue-router, mobile-chrome

I notice a lot of errors in Sentry with the following stack trace:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.__esModule')
  at isESModule(./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js:1955:3)
  at ? (./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js:1882:27)
  at promiseReactionJob([native code])
```

I'm having a lot of trouble reproducing the error myself and figuring out what causes it. Looking at the vue-router source, it comes from this function:

```js
  function isESModule (obj) {
    return obj.__esModule || (hasSymbol && obj[Symbol.toStringTag] === 'Module')
  }
```

So `obj` is undefined. If we go one level up we get this function:

```js
  function resolveAsyncComponents (matched) {
    return function (to, from, next) {
      var hasAsync = false;
      var pending = 0;
      var error = null;

      flatMapComponents(matched, function (def, _, match, key) {
        // if it's a function and doesn't have cid attached,
        // assume it's an async component resolve function.
        // we are not using Vue's default async resolving mechanism because
        // we want to halt the navigation until the incoming component has been
        // resolved.
        if (typeof def === 'function' && def.cid === undefined) {
          hasAsync = true;
          pending++;

          var resolve = once(function (resolvedDef) {
            if (isESModule(resolvedDef)) {
              resolvedDef = resolvedDef.default;
            }
            // save resolved on async factory in case it's used elsewhere
            def.resolved = typeof resolvedDef === 'function'
              ? resolvedDef
              : _Vue.extend(resolvedDef);
            match.components[key] = resolvedDef;
            pending--;
            if (pending <= 0) {
              next();
            }
          });

...
```

So it looks like `resolvedDef` is undefined.

My guess is that the Vue router resolves an async component successfully but it ends up undefined and there's nothing in the code to account for that case.

I'm using vue-router 3.1.3 and these errors always happen only on iOS (Safari or Chrome).

I've tried Googling the error and I can't seem to find a single reference to it anywhere else. I'm also not able to post an issue on the vue-router Github because I'm not able to provide a minimal reproduction.

Often (but not always) Sentry also shows this console log preceding the error:

```
console [vue-analytics] An error occured! Please check your connection or disable your AD blocker
logger console
extra {"arguments":["[vue-analytics] An error occured! Please check your connection or disable your AD blocker"]}
```

I'm not sure if that's related though.

One crazy solution I'm thinking of is deployed a patched version of vue-router where it throws an error with more useful context in the case where `resolvedDef` is undefined. That error would hopefully end up in our Sentry logs.

What's causing this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forked the vue-router library and patched `resolveAsyncComponents` with this line:

```js
if (!resolvedDef) {
  window.onerror(`router wtf ${matched.join(',')} ${def} ${_} ${match} ${key} ${pending} ${hasAsync} ${error}`);
}
```

Eventually the following error appeared in Sentry:

```
router wtf [object Object] function(){return u(Promise.all([n.e("dashboard~orders~products~publicUser"),n.e("dashboard~discounts~products~publicUser"),n.e("orders~publicUser~tips"),n.e("publicUser~tips"),n.e("publicUser")]).then(n.bind(null,"89c6")))...
```

In production, our Vue app seems to load these components with an initiator called bootstrap:

[image: asycn component loading]

Then it hit me that we use the following wrapper around every single async component import in `router.js`:

```js
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        name: 'dashboard',
        component: () =>
          handleChunkLoadError(
            import(/* webpackChunkName: 'dashboard' */ '../views/Dashboard')
          ),
      },
```

```js
function handleChunkLoadError(importPromise) {
  return importPromise.catch(() => {
    Vue.toasted.error('Network error encountered', {
      duration: null,
      action: {
        text: 'Reload',
        onClick: () => window.location.reload(),
      },
    });
  });
}
```

It's supposed to show a toast that allows the user to refresh the page if a chunk failed to load.

But we were forgetting to pass along the error to vue-router:

```js
function handleChunkLoadError(importPromise) {
  return importPromise.catch(error => {
    Vue.toasted.error('Network error encountered', {
      duration: null,
      action: {
        text: 'Reload',
        onClick: () => window.location.reload(),
      },
    });

    return error;
  });
}
```

Returning the error in the `.catch` handler fixes the issue.